# Send bulk push notifications using FCM firebase node js express

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, queue

I've an admin panel and the admin has provision to send push notifications to all the users of my application using REST API. I'm getting fcm tokens from db.

I've referred the firebase docs [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/admin/send-messages) and we can only send up to 1000 messages to devices in a single request.

My application has lot of users. So how can I send notifications to all devices? I've referred the library [kue](https://github.com/Automattic/kue) for queue process. But couldn't get the complete solution. Kindly anyone advice me to achieve this. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can send requests in chunks.

Let's say you have an array of device registration_ids.

You can use lodash or any other library to make chunks of 1000.

```
const chunks = _.chunk(registration_ids, 1000);

const promises = _.map(chunks, (e) => {
    return sendFcm(e, message);
});

return Promise.all(promises);
```

Comment: It will wait for completing all the process

Comment: It depends on if you want to wait for it. You can issue the request and forget about it.

Comment: Does this work well with say, 1 million push notifications?